# who manufactures HPs desktop SATA SSD drives?

Tags: discussion

HP 160GB SATA Solid State Drive LZ704AA

http://h30094.www3.hp.com/searchresults.asp?store_id=3&search_id=16&dept_id=113&price_min=-1&price_max=2147483647&rank_on=sasssearch&rank_dir=asc&search=showcase&pagemode=ca&price_matrix=SMB-BOOK1&advanced_search=1

Comment: Is meta really an appropriate place for this question?

Comment: This shouldn't be in meta. And it shouldn't really be closed. I asked a perfectly legit question about the OEM of HP SAS SSDs (Pliant). See: http://serverfault.com/questions/307433/who-manufactures-the-enterprise-sas-ssd-drives-sold-by-hp

Comment: This should be sent back to main and reopened.

Comment: Was this question migrated to meta through votes or by a mod? If it was votes perhaps those responsible should be directed to the FAQ of both SF and MSF. If it was a mod can you please send it back and reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

The SATA SSD you're inquiring about is an [Intel 320 160GB unit](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/solid-state-drives-320-series.html).

[image]